# How to deactivate past shortcodes in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Recently I changed the theme of my site, and I found many of my articles use a shortcode like this

```
[box]
    ....
[/box]
```

My new theme does not support it and I actually don't need this shortcode to function. I thought I could just write a empty function for the shortcode in function.php, like this

```
function shortcode_box() {
    return "";
}
add_shortcode('box', 'shortcode_box');
```

but it's not working.

Do you know any method to deactivate this short code?

Comment: use `remove_shortcode()`

Comment: Funny thing is the empty shortcode not working... Try putting it in a mini-plugin.

Comment: When you say "not working", what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to leave the `[box]` bits in the posts and/or pages, but have them not do anything? Try a shortcode that passes through the content unchanged:

```
function shortcode_box( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'box', 'shortcode_box' );
```

(For enclosing shortcodes, the return value of the function is used to replace the entire shortcode.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `remove_shortcode()`

```
remove_shortcode('box');
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_shortcode